# Accessing control in subform from another subform

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have 3 tables (Main, ED, and OP) the relations are 
Main to ED is 1 to Many
Main to OP is 1 to Many

for that I created 3 Forms (frmM, frmE, and frmO)

the frmM has 2 Sub-Forms frmE and frmO (both frmE and frmO are inside frmM data list)

What I want is : once the value of a text-box txtE1 in frmE changes, the text-box txtO1 in frmO will be disabled

I used this code inside frmE

```
FrmO.txtO1.Enabled = False
```

although this does not give any error and when debug I can see the value of the text-box changes in the Watch window, yet nothing actually happens to the textbox in the form

I have look at many questions in StackOverFlow and googled for more than 3 days

[Requery subform from another subform, problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015229/requery-subform-from-another-subform-problems)

http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?900897-Set-Value-In-A-SubForm

I tried

```
Forms("frmM")("frmO").Controls("txtO1").Enabled = False
Me.Parent!txtO1.Enabled = False
Forms.frmM.frmO.Form.txtO1.Enabled = False
```

all of them not working.

anyone can help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`Me.Parent!frmO_Container.Form!txtO1.Enabled = False`

Where `frmO_Container` is the name of the subform control on frmM that houses frmO itself

EDIT: and if you aren't already, place this code in the On Change event for `txt01`

When referring to subforms, it's important to distinguish between the subform control on the parent form, and the subform itself.